# Convert repeated-measures ANOVA into linear mixed-effects model

Tags: r, regression, anova

I am a beginner to R and it is my first time asking a question here, so thanks in advance for your patience. I would like to convert a repeated-measures ANOVA that I run into SPSS to a linear mixed-effects model in R.

In the SPSS model, I compare two within-subject variables (Wrong_extrinsic & Wrong_intrinsic) and I want to control for five covariates that have the same structure as the DV (e.g. Pain_extrinsic & Pain_intrinsic) [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEK1.png). For R, I converted the data into a long format, so that Condition is dummy coded with 0=intrinsic and 1=extrinsic.

If I had no covariates, the model would be `lmer(Wrong ~ Condition + (1|id), d)`. I was wondering what the right way is to include the covariates into the model as the covariates have the same repeated-measures structure as the DV (intrinsic vs. extrinsic).

I was wondering if this is the correct model: `lmer(Wrong ~ Condition + Condition * Covariate1 + Condition * Covariate2 + ... + (1|id), d)`?

I would very much appreciate your help!

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: It sounds like condition needs to be a `factor`, _not_ 0 and 1. You don't need to code dummies manually in R. Your suggested model could be right, (although you don't need `Condition` and `Condition * ....` since the `*` expands into lower order terms), but I cannot say from your very limited explanation.

Comment: Hi Chris! Your model looks good, as long as the variable type of condition is factor. Like Axeman said, you can write the same model more concisely (assuming you want all interactions between all covariates, which might not be a great idea because of overfitting) like so: lmer(Wrong ~ Condition * Covariate1 * Covariate2, etc...). 

Additionally, having only random slopes makes your model pretty restrictive, even though it's functionally equivalent to RM ANOVA. It's better to include random slopes as well, unless you have strong reason not to.